# pyspark rdd map __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```py
def link2Page(x):
    tisPageout = all_page_df.select("out_degree").where("page='%s'" % x[0]).take(1)[0].out_degree  # all link point to x._1
    if x[1] == None or len(x[1]) < 1:
        return Row(x[0], 1 /float(N), tisPageout)

    newScore = 0.0
    for li in x[1]:
        pageInfo = all_page_df.select("*").where("page='%s'" % li).take(1)[0]  # all link point to x._1
        newScore += pageInfo.score / pageInfo.out_degree

    newScore = newScore * d_global + (1 - d_global) / float(N)

    return Row(x[0], newScore, tisPageout)

in_rdd.map(link2Page)
```

all_page_df  has 3 columns: page, score, out_degree.

in_rdd has 2 columns: page, inlinks.

inlinks is a type of list.

For every item in inlinks, i want to find its corresponding score and out_degree in dataframe all_page_df.

When i run this piece of code, bugs:

> pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error
>   occurred while calling o166.__getnewargs__. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
>   Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You are trying with your map to access another dataframe. That is not possible. actions must be executed on driver, they cannot be executer on workers.

Comment: thanks. is there other way to work around it and solve the problem?

Comment: I do not know exactly. I need to refactor your code. Joins or merges would be probably the solution you are looking for.